# Add value to some cases in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a  numeric column called store that has some negative values. I'd like to add 1440 to the negative , but am having trouble. My data looks like this:

```
   score
  1  816
  2 -200
  3  976
  4 -376
  5    1
  6  121
  7 -331
```

I can replace the values using `temp[temp$score< 0] <-8888`.

But, I when I try to add value to the variable using: `temp[temp$score < 0] <- temp$score + 1440`, I get an warning that says:

```
Warning message: In temp$score[temp$score < 0] <- temp$score + 1440 
:number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

And then I get some odd values returned:

```
  score
1   816
2  2256
3   976
4  1240
5     1
6   121
7  2416
```

Am I calling the function wrong or am I selecting the cases wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your warning message, it seems like you were trying to do the following:

```
temp$score[temp$score < 0] <- temp$score + 1440
```

The problem here is that you are replacing a vector with one that is a different length, as the warning message suggests. You shortened the left-hand side of the assignment, but not the right-hand side - the solution would be to shorten the right-hand side too, as follows:

```
score <- c(816,-200,976,-376,1,121,-331)
temp <- data.frame(score)
temp$score[temp$score < 0] <- temp$score[temp$score < 0] + 1440
```

Comment: No problem! I was not able to run `temp[temp$score<0 <- temp$score+1440`... In this case I had to assume what you were trying to do from your warning message. As a heads up, it'll be much easier for people to answer questions if they can copy your code and run it - so it's a good idea to check if you can do that yourself when you ask questions.

Comment: Just for fun, you can do it this way too :  `temp$score <- temp$score + 1440*(temp$score<0)` . I suspect that for very large vectors this may be slower, but it's often handy to make use of implicit conversion from logical to ones and zeroes.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft your method has the advantage of working if any of score is NA valued. Otherwise you end up trying to subscript with an NA, which is a fail... You can fix this by wrapping with a `which` function...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, if there's NA data, then subscripting will fail:

```
> temp
   score z
1    123 1
2     NA 2
3    345 3
4 -10783 4
5   1095 5
6    873 6
> temp$score[temp$score < 0] <- temp$score[temp$score < 0] + 1440
Error in temp$score[temp$score < 0] <- temp$score[temp$score < 0] + 1440 :  
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

So use `which`:

```
> temp$score[which(temp$score < 0)] <- temp$score[which(temp$score < 0)] + 1440
> temp
  score z
1   123 1
2    NA 2
3   345 3
4 -9343 4
5  1095 5
6   873 6
```

Comment: Hey,  no fair referencing your own comments!  :-)